# Is there a single XPath expression I can use to navigate XML in a CDATA section?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to figure out how to use XPath to get the exceptionID and instrumentID values out of the XML snippet in the following XML document (yes having XML in the CDATA is a little odd, but that's what I get from the 3rd party service)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <exception>
    <info>
      <![CDATA[
        <info>
          <exceptionID>1</exceptionID>
          <instrumentID>1</instrumentID>
        </info>
      ]]>
    </info>
</exception>
```

Is it possible to get the values in one XPath statement?

I'm using javax.xml.xpath.XPath inside Java (JDK 1.5 with Xalan 2.7.1 and Xerces 2.9.1), e.g.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

Long exceptionId  = new Long(((Double)xpath.evaluate(this.exceptionIdXPath, 
                               document, XPathConstants.NUMBER)).longValue());
```

It's the this.exceptionIdXPath variable that I'm not sure how to set, I know for example that:

`/exception/info/text()/info/exceptionID`  won't work (text() returns the data inside the CDATA but with no 'knowledge' that it is XML)

Comment: What XPath/XSLT engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using javax.xml.xpath.XPath inside Java (JDK 1.5 with Xalan 2.7.1 and Xerces 2.9.1)

Comment: XPath 3.0 could do that with one expression `parse-xml(/exception/info)/info/exceptionID` using parse-xml http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/functions/intro/parse-xml.xml, Saxon 9.3 http://www.saxonica.com/ is implemented in Java and supports XPath 3.0 in its commercial versions.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - Thanks, I trialled this and it worked, but introduces an extra lib to our solution for one (fairly minor in comparison) issue.  I've left a note in the code and my issue tracker to revisit if/when we move to XPath and its implementing libs

Comment: FYI, something's malformed about that prologue: `<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>` I hope your 3rd party didn't really give you XML with those backslashes in there?

Comment: @karianna: Don't use unparsed data as parseable data. Bad design choice.

Comment: @Alejandro - Agree in principle, I'm working with the 3rd party to send 'better' XML in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. But anything inside the CDATA section is a string and won't be part of the DOM. Therefore, you have to use XPath's string manipulation functions.

In XPath you can use substring-before and substring-after. Something like this may work:

```
substring-before(substring-after(/exception/info,"<exceptionID>"), "</exceptionID>")
```

Comment: I went with this solution which worked, thanks for the substring example, I'd started to try it but your version was certainly more compact than mine :-)

Comment: Without the "specific solution" indication nor parsing recomendation, this falls into the same kind of answer as "use RegExp to parse XML".

Comment: @Alejandro Yeah it does, but it does mean all I have to do in future is swap out my dependency injected XPath statement once the 3rd party fixes their XML.  So for me it's a pragmatic solution

Comment: @Alejandro: Absolutely not! Because the contents of a CDATA are *not* XML. The CDATA declares it to *not* be XML. It may look like XML, but the CDATA section was likely added as a crude shortcut because sometimes the contents are not valid XML. It boils down to what @GaryF said in his comment: the 3rd party is misusing or misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be very specific to the tools you're using (it would be good to know what platform and libraries you're using), but generally you can't do this in a single step. The whole point of CDATA is that it's raw character data and not necessarily XML.

What you can do is capture the text() in exception/info (basically the contents of your CDATA block) and create a new XML document (in memory) from that, and then use XPath over that document.

The detailed steps for this are platform-dependant.

Comment: To be honest, the best solution is to speak to the 3rd party about their misuse/misunderstanding of structured data in an unstructured element. I'm guessing that's not possible though.